# Background height of div according to content for mine project it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, background

In industrukt.pl/dev/ap/barbara.html I need a background color of article section (for mine is white) to 100% of photos. Now I have added a constant height but this is not good.
When browser window is resized to for example mobile or tablet resolution background color is not 100% of photos content.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE2Fh.png

How can I fix that?

My code html:

```
<div class="content">
    <aside>
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-bottom:30px"><a href="index.html#tresc">wybrane prace - home</a></li>
            <li style="margin-top:30px;" class="selected"><a href="#">Barbara</a></li>
            <li><a href="fellig.html">Fellig</a></li>
            <li>Nix oder Langeweile</li>
            <li>Tereska</li>
            <li>Lee B&W</li>
            <li>Lee</li>
            <li>Eine Zusammenarbeit</li>
            <li>Fritzi</li>
            <li>St. Annas</li>
            <li>Ania</li>
            <li>Rosa</li>
            <li>Hannes Part I</li>
            <li>Hannes Part II</li>
            <li>Fotoalbum</li>
            <li>Michał & Kuba</li>
            <li>Selbstportrait</li>
            <li>Lizl</li>
            <li>Karolina</li>
            <li>Hannes Express</li>
            <li>Franziskas Familie</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <article style="margin-top:135px">
        <div class="photos">
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/1.jpg"/>
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/2.jpg"/>
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/3.jpg"/>
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/4.jpg"/>
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/5.jpg"/>
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/6.jpg"/>
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/7.jpg"/>
            <img class="thumbnail"  src="img/gallery/barbara/8.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </article>

    <!-- End Content -->
</div>
<div class="bcg"></div>
```

CSS code:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    background-color: #fff;   
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

article {
    padding-left: 37px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 272px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.photos {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.bcg {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Ballmer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhh_GeBPOhs), but anyway: Code, code, code! ;-) Please provide your code!

Comment: @Stano my background color of content div is not height as text/photos in divs in that wrapping div

Comment: Just as a comment: Using `float: left` and `position: absolute` at the same time does not make sense.

Comment: @Stano I think that cleaner div is not working. Check this @ 
http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap/barbara.html or http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap/index.html

Comment: @Stano that make me sth like that: http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap/barbara.html
Background color shows only behind photos div not behind all content div.

If you want I can zip whole website for you to see in own local pc

Comment: @Stano added everything what you created for me, but look
http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap/
There is still gap below aside and on the right (1 or 2 pixels)
http://i.imgur.com/GFMKDn4.png?1

Comment: @Stano when I modify '.content' to constant height like 2000px background fill everything also that gaps what I mentioned above in comment but still website is to long. When is 100% it have only 510px of height (that told me inspect panel in FF).

Comment: @Stano I do that... :C
That is no working. So what i need to do? Rewrite whole website and make magic to work that content div?

You looked at linked rar of whole website?

That is to strange that we can not to make it work well

As you can see at http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap still .content is not the same height as photos div.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a semicolon `;` after `height`

```
.content {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;   
padding-bottom: 30px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

When you look into the console, you will see the browser complain about

> Expected end of value but found 'background-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'height'.  Declaration dropped.

or some similar message.

To see the whole content, remove the `overflow: hidden`. You don't have this in your website at `http://industrukt.pl/dev/ap/barbara.html` anyway.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9JZf/) for playing.

Comment: @user2089517, that's because of `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @user2089517 This is because you have overflow hidden. See updated answer and JSFiddle.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell I removed overflow:hidden and nothing changed.
Menu on the left and photos are without background color.

See @ http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap/barbara.html

Comment: @user2089517 See the JSFiddle; background of photos is red and background of remaining content is white as specified in the CSS.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I used all of changed things in JSFiddle, and still don't have background color to whole content:C
You can use http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap/www.rar

Comment: @user2089517 I looked at your website. In `main.css:232`, you have `.photos { background-color: #fff; ...`, which is white. When I change this to some other color like `red` or `blue`, the background changes as expected.

Comment: @OlafDietsche but what about rest of website? You have background #fff behind menu on the left etc? I dont have it :C

Comment: @user2089517 All the same here, there's no `background-color` defined. When I add `background-color: green` to `aside` the background changes accordingly.

Comment: @OlafDietsche ok, I added a background-color to article and aside like u recommend but when I sroll lil bit I can see a gap like here:
http://i.imgur.com/A1i583H.png

Thats strange 'coz background-color is in .content also

Comment: @Stano added, but don't help very well. Take a look @ http://industrukt.pl/dev/stack_ap/barbara.html

Yellow is only added to stricte menu on the left not to gap above, below and few pixels on the right.

I really don't get it how is that so difficult to make that work

Comment: @Stano in index.html the big background photo should only appers when you load website like now, after moving down should dissapear like now.
on the rest of sites like barbara.html there is no need to see this image

Comment: @Stano I can remove script in barbara.html and then my background will be white like I need but in index.html problem is still actual.
Also I noticed that if .content is cutting, little line on the right of aside is also dissapear.

If .content would be long as photos are that all will be awesome.